# Typescript Type Casting For Function Return Type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm confused with the following function expression:

```
export default () => <TypeA<TypeB, TypeC>>{ function implementation details...}
```

My first thought is that it is exporting an anonymous function, and casting its return type to `TypeA<TypeB, TypeC>`. But I couldn't find any documents on function return type casting like this, and if that is the case, I think it would make more sense to write it as this:

```
export default (): TypeA<TypeB, TypeC> => { function implementation details...}
```

Can anyone help me understand the syntax of the first expression? Is it a return type casting? If not, then what is it?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example? I'm having a hard time trying to make this syntax valid at all. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=3.9.2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA28AUBKOAXgD44AeAbzmQggC44BnGKASwDsBzOAX2KqjAY6KOzgUecVIynsAnrwCwAKCA

Comment: @AlexWayne While I was trying to fix the syntax error in your link, I looked back at the original code(I was struggling with) and realized that the code inside the bracket is actually not function implementation, it is an object with complex methods. So it is casting an object instead of a function return type. Thanks for the link!